# Sender Cyclic Redundancy Check Code - Why isn't my code working?

Tags: c++

Given a frame and generator, no. of bits in generator is n

1. you have to put n-1 number of zeroes behind frame
2. then the first n bits of frame are XORed with the generator
3. this is continued until the remainder has n-1 digits
4. then last n-1 digits of frame(which were the zeroes we added in step 1) are replaced by n-1 digits of
   remainder
5. this is to be displayed
   It executes, takes input but the cursor just blinks instead of giving output

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class CRC
{
    int frame[32], generator[10],f,g;
    public:
    void input();
    void check();
}obj;

void CRC::input()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"Enter length of frame:";
    cin>>obj.f;
    cout<<"Enter frame:";
    for(i=0;i<obj.f;i++)
    {
        cin>>obj.frame[i];
    }
    cout<<"Enter length of generator:";
    cin>>obj.g;
    cout<<"Enter generator:";
    for(i=0;i<obj.g;i++)
    {
        cin>>obj.generator[i];
    }
    obj.f=obj.f+obj.g-1;
 
    obj.check();
}
void CRC::check()
{

    int p[32],k=0,i;
    for(i=0;i<obj.f;i++)
    {
        p[i]=obj.frame[i];
    }

    while((obj.f-k)>=g)
    {

        for(i=k;i<obj.g+k;i++)
        {
            p[i]=p[i]^generator[i];
        }
        for(i=obj.g+k;i<obj.f;i++)
        {
            p[i]=frame[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<obj.f;i++)
        {
            if(p[i]==1)
            {
                k=i;
                break;
            }
        }


    }


    for(i=obj.f-obj.g;i<obj.f;i++)
    {
        obj.frame[i]=p[i];
    }
    cout<<"Original message:";
    for(i=0;i<obj.f;i++)
    {
        cout<<obj.frame[i];
    }

}
int main()
{
    obj.input();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why isn't my code working?* -- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Side note: why are you using the `obj` object in all your member functions? That completely eliminates the ability to use multiple instances of the class. It is a design choice I am not familiar with.